# Preventing user form from being activated when setting a print area

Tags: excel, vba

There is probably a very simple answer to this.
I have a designed a capture sheet on an Excel spreadsheet and have used a DatePicker for cell D2. So far, so good. When I go to close the spreadsheet, I have a small macro that sets the print area B1:M37 ready to print. As this happens, the macro activates the Date Picker which has to be manually closed before I can continue with the printing. How can I either suppress the event happening, or use code to close the user form. My code is as follows:

```
Sub Test_a_Print_again()
    Range("B1:M37").Select 
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$M$37"
       ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub  

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then frmCalendar.Show        '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SelectionChange event is being triggered by the line:

```
Range("B1:M37").Select
```

There's a couple of things you could do:

- Don't use Select. It's not clear that it's needed here, and it's one
  of the top VBA bad practices unless absolutely necessary.
- In your Worksheet_SelectionChange event, if you only want it to run
  if D2 and only D2 is selected, you could add another condition:

  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then frmCalendar.Show

But again, I'd just get rid of the Select statement(s).